# Problem with sending mail via tor from freemail

Tags: email

I have problem with sending mail via tor. I have freemail seznam.cz and centrum.cz. After I updated on Tor Browser  5.5a4 I have problem. I send mail, but nobody gets my mail.

Comment: Are they online services similar to Gmail? Are you sending them from a web portal (like gmail.com), or from an email client on your computer set up with Tor as a proxy? Are you able to send mail to yourself?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks: he was mentioning using TBB, so is assume he uses a webmail-service...

Comment: @jenda: please keep in mind that you are using [**alpha software**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle#Alpha)!!! - does the same problems occur with the stable branch?

Comment: Yep, saw that, but just thought I'd check :) (It's possible to run the Tor executable from the Browser Bundle, and use it as a proxy, without actually using the browser itself.)